# Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll missing ListViewByQuery

Tags: 2010

I have installed Sharepoint 2010 on my Windows 7 machine (yes, I know it's not supported).  I'm looking for ListViewByQuery, but it doesn't seem to be in the DLL I have.  The DLL is version 14.0.6029.1000.  As I understand it, the class should be part of Microsoft.Sharepoint.WebControls.

Any ideas as to why it would be missing if I have this version of the DLL?

Thanks in advance.

edit: It turns out that the class name resolves in Visual Studio 2010, but not in Visual Studio 2012, even though they are both referencing the same Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll.  Strange

Comment: Mandatory obvious question: Are you `using` the namespace in your C#?

Answer (score 0):

So, to answer my own question.  It turns out the class was missing from the DLL when I created a new Sharepoint project as a Sandboxed solution as opposed to a Farm solution.  When I chose a farm solution, it showed up even in Visual Studio 2012.  I knew that things would be hidden from intellisense when they weren't accessible in a sandboxed solution, but I didn't think they were removed from the DLL altogether.

Comment: Well, I don't know how are you "inspecting" the dll, but for me it's there, even if I create a Sandboxed solution with VS2010. Is it VS2012 who is hiding it if it's a sandboxed solution? Or do you have Resharper?